# "Gtk WARNING: gtk_disable_setlocale() must be called before gtk_init()" on calling plot in gdl (gnu data language)

Tags: ubuntu, gtk, idl, idl-programming-language, gdl

I installed GDL, the IDL alternative, to run some IDL code for my project. But when I try to call plot function in GDL it gives the following error and exits:

*(gdl:1003695): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:57:44.888: gtk_disable_setlocale() must be called before gtk_init()
Segmentation fault (core dumped)*

I am using ubuntu 20.04 with kubuntu-desktop. Any suggestions are welcome.
[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCu1z.png)

Answer (score 0):

GDL uses the plplot and wxwidgets library, this looks like a wxwidgets library problem. Anyway, the good place to report bugs or ask for advice for GDL is on [their github repository](https://github.com/gnudatalanguage/gdl/issues)

Comment: Thank you! I solved the problem by compiling plplot using the source file to /usr/local/ and then compiling gdl with flag -DPLPLOTDIR=/usr/local.